# Comparing floating-point performance of Gflops and SPECfp

Tags: performance

I have performance numbers for two servers, but one reports Gflops and the other a SPECfp score. Is there a simple rule of thumb for comparing these two units of measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this presentation](https://hpcrd.lbl.gov/scidac09/talks/Murphy-SciDAC-2009.pdf) Real Floating Point Apps don’t do many FLOPS, but do lots of data movement, and in case of SPECfp it is circa 30% (based on the 8th slide). But as you can see in the presentation, you cannot really compare the two.